# convert json to swift object return nill?

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to convert JSON file to swift object, but I could not figure it out why it returns nill. as you use from code, I have two objects one Stakeholder and other MHSGroup I created a struct to hold data colled 
StakeholderMHSGroup

```
  struct StakeholderMHSGroup : Codable {
        var stakeholders:[Stakeholder]?
        var mhsGroups:[MhsGroup]?
    }
```

main swift

```
let jsonStr =  "{\"stakeholders\":[{\"id\":\"d95bb600-f63b-4ec7-bd2f-d14bdf1c145f\",\"firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Doe\",\"emailAddress\":\"John.Doe@mail.com\",\"salutation\":\"Ms\"},{\"id\":\"d95bb600-f63b-4ec7-bd2f-d14bdf1c145d\",\"firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Doe\",\"emailAddress\":\"John.Doe@mail.com\",\"salutation\":\"Ms\"},{\"id\":\"d95bb600-f63b-4ec7-bd2f-d14bdf1c545f\",\"firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Doe\",\"emailAddress\":\"John.Doe@mail.com\",\"salutation\":\"Ms\"},{\"id\":\"d95bb600-f63b-4ec7-bd2f-d14baf1c145f\",\"firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Doe\",\"emailAddress\":\"John.Doe@mail.com\",\"salutation\":\"Ms\"}],\"mhsGroups\":[{\"id\":\"495919eb-dcbc-48c5-99f5-48f6790b79e3\",\"name\":\"Group1\",\"membersCount\":5,\"createdDate\":\"2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z\"},{\"id\":\"495919eb-dcbc-48c5-99f5-48f6290b79e3\",\"name\":\"Group1\",\"membersCount\":5,\"createdDate\":\"2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z\"},{\"id\":\"495919eb-dcbc-48c5-99f5-48f6790b79e4\",\"name\":\"Group1\",\"membersCount\":5,\"createdDate\":\"2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z\"},{\"id\":\"495919eb-dcbc-48c5-99f5-48f6790b79e2\",\"name\":\"Group1\",\"membersCount\":5,\"createdDate\":\"2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z\"}]}"
```

> "{"stakeholders":[{"id":"d95bb600-f63b-4ec7-bd2f-d14bdf1c145f","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","emailAddress":"John.Doe@mail.com","salutation":"Ms"},{"id":"d95bb600-f63b-4ec7-bd2f-d14bdf1c145d","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","emailAddress":"John.Doe@mail.com","salutation":"Ms"},{"id":"d95bb600-f63b-4ec7-bd2f-d14bdf1c545f","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","emailAddress":"John.Doe@mail.com","salutation":"Ms"},{"id":"d95bb600-f63b-4ec7-bd2f-d14baf1c145f","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","emailAddress":"John.Doe@mail.com","salutation":"Ms"}],"mhsGroups":[{"id":"495919eb-dcbc-48c5-99f5-48f6790b79e3","name":"Group1","membersCount":5,"createdDate":"2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"},{"id":"495919eb-dcbc-48c5-99f5-48f6290b79e3","name":"Group1","membersCount":5,"createdDate":"2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"},{"id":"495919eb-dcbc-48c5-99f5-48f6790b79e4","name":"Group1","membersCount":5,"createdDate":"2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"},{"id":"495919eb-dcbc-48c5-99f5-48f6790b79e2","name":"Group1","membersCount":5,"createdDate":"2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"}]}"

```
var data:Data?
        data = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8)!


        let userGroup = try!  JSONDecoder().decode(StakeholderMHSGroup.self, from: data!)



        print(userGroup)
```

> update debug error
>
> hread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:
>   Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Double,
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue:
>   "mhsGroups", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0",
>   intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "createdDate", intValue: nil)],
>   debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data
>   instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Can you provide your JSON data in an unescaped format? i.e. not in a swift string.

Comment: see the update?

Comment: The keys don't match. The JSON has keys such as `Stakeholders`, but your models have keys such as `stakeholders`.

Comment: fixed the match I have another error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the error message, you seem to have declared `createdDate` as a `Double`, but in the JSON, the value associated with `createdDate` is a string.

You should declare `createDate` as a `Date` (you could always use `createdDate.timeIntervalSince1970` if you want a `Double`), and set `dateDecodingStrategy` of the decoder to `iso8601`, because your dates seem to be in that format:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoer()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
// you shouldn't really use "try!" here...
let userGroup = try! decoder.decode(StakeholderMHSGroup.self, from: data!)
```